# What is the best way to run junit tests with different values?

Tags: junit

I want to know what the best way to rerun a junit test with multiple values to make sure all edge cases of a function are covered. (usually each file in a test directory, or set of values that cover all major edge cases)

So, a simplified pseudo example of the kind of testing I want to do

```
@testEach([1,3,5,7,11])
public void isPrime(int number) {
  assert("is prime", true, MyClass.isPrime(number);
}

@testEach([2,4,6,8,9,10])
public void isNotPrime(int number) {
  assert("is not prime", false, MyClass.isPrime(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under jUnit5, this can be achieved with `@ParameterizedTest`.

```java
public class IsPrimeTest {
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} should be prime")
    @ValueSource(ints = {1, 3, 5, 7, 11})
    public void isPrime(int number) {
        Assertions.assertThat(MyClass.isPrime(number))
                .isTrue();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} should not be prime")
    @ValueSource(ints = {2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10})
    public void isNotPrime(int number) {
        Assertions.assertThat(MyClass.isPrime(number))
                .isTrue();
    }
}
```

Note that there are multiple sources you can use

- `@ValueSource`
- `@EnumSource`
- `@CsvSource`
- `@MethodSource`

See [Guide to JUnit 5 Parameterized Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5)

Under jUnit4, this was achieved with JUnitParams.
See [Introduction to JUnitParams](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-params)